# How to trigger an event when any of CheckState values in CheckListBox is changed

Tags: c#, winforms, checklistbox

I have a CheckListBox in c# and I am trying to trigger an event whenever one of the checkstates in the box is changed. The event purpose is to change some RichTextBox.

I have this piece of code, but it triggers the event only when one of the check boxes is turning from checked to unchecked, for some reason.
I tried to figure out what is wrong with my code with no success.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
    private void clbAllRooms_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        //If the checkstate changed, update price  
        //It updates price only when the state turns from Checked to Uncheck
        if (e.NewValue != e.CurrentValue)
            Update_rtbPrice();
    }
```

Comment: What language is that ? You should edit your question to add proper tags if you want to touch the correct audience. At least add the language name. You could also fix the question title to remove the trailing '>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is no doubt located in your Update_rtbPrice() method.  It would have to call the list box' GetItemChecked() method to do something meaningful and that's a problem when you make the method call from the event handler.  The item check state doesn't change until *after* the event runs.

A workaround is to delay the call so it runs after the control's state is updated.  Like this:

```
    private void clbAllRooms_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => Update_rtbPrice()));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I was trying to solve this problem all day...I would never have thougt of that

Comment: Nice catch.  I didn't think about the repercussions about him calling that method during the event.